# Unable to echo specific line to a .vbs file

Tags: command-line, vbscript, echo, command-prompt

The command prompt complains that it is unable to recoqnize the command.So i was thinking i needed to escape something that looked like a start of a command to the echo with the ^ character.

This is the exact line:

```
echo Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\Beta.lnk")>>%temp%\CreateFirefoxBetaShortcut.vbs
```

I tried:

```
echo ^Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\Beta.lnk")>>%temp%\CreateFirefoxBetaShortcut.vbs
```

But no luck.Im puzzled by this because it correctly enters much more complex lines but for some reason it want's to treat this line as a command not a simple text.
I can post the full .vbs including the other lines if that helps somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand ("&") character has a special meaning for "cmd". Therefore, it must be preceded with a caret ("^"), like this:

```
echo Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\Beta.lnk")>>%temp%\CreateFirefoxBetaShortcut.vbs
```

Comment: Thank you.This worked nicely.Every day i learn something new.